# Explicitly specifying value for an auto-incremented column in MySql

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

MySql forces me to specify value for an auto-incremented column. I do not understand why i need to do that.

I have created a table with the following columns

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Aask 
( task_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT, 
SUBJECT VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
start_date DATE DEFAULT NULL, 
end_date DATE DEFAULT NULL, 
description VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (task_id) 
);`

After creating the above table, when i try to insert rows using

`INSERT INTO flask
VALUES ('Subject1','1892-12-27','1994-11-29','detailed description'),
 ('Subject2','1992-01-17','1694-11-31','HTML view');`

I get an error message which says

Query: INSERT INTO flask VALUES ('Subject1','1892-12-27','1994-11-29','detailed description'), ('Subject2','1992-01-17','1694-11-31','H...

Error Code: 1136
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I know there are 5 columns in the table and i have given only 4 values in value list but why am i forced to mention value for auto increment column?

This may sound basic to most of you guys but i am just getting started with MySql so any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use this insert

```
 INSERT INTO flask (SUBJECT, start_date, end_date, description ) values 'Subject1','1892-12-27','1994-11-29','detailed description');
```

Comment: But why is that the following query does not work ?`INSERT INTO flask 
VALUES ('Subject2','1997-01-01','1999-12-31','inserted text present here')`;

Comment: since you don't specify the columns to insert, mysql expects all columns values